# How can I restore the VDC RAM to usable text mode after clearing memory for hi-res graphics?

Tags: commodore, commodore-128

So, I've got a C-128 with only 16K of VDC video RAM. I've finished my lovely high-resolution graphics routine on the RGBI display and want to exit to BASIC with a functional 80-column text screen, ideally without zapping the contents of main memory. What are my options?

CINT doesn't redo the character set copy from ROM to VDC RAM;
RESET erases everything.

Is there an in-between option I could use other than rolling my own copy-ROM-to-VDC logic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution thanks to Compute's *Mapping the Commodore 128*, though the call is also documented in the C-128 *Programmer's Reference Guide*. There's a kernal jump table entry called `DLCHAR` at $FF62 (*Mapping the 128* calls it `JINIT80`) that initializes the VDC RAM from the character ROM. A call to that gets things working again.

That routine doesn't touch the character matrix or attribute RAM, so you'll still want to clear that; a call to `CINT` ($FF81) or just printing the clear-screen character $93 (assuming the output channel is set to the 80-column display) will do the trick.